# Could quantum computing help solving the Eternity II puzzle?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, speedup, research

First of all, since I am not a specialist, sorry if this question does not make sense. But, I can't resist to ask as I have not found any direct information while googling.

I hope some of you know/remember the [Eternity II puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternity_II_puzzle). According to its Wikipedia page, it has still not been solved.

Here is my "simple" question(s): (1a) **Could quantum computing help in solving that particular problem?** (1b) Is this puzzle a problem within the scope of what QC can do faster? If yes, (2) could we already write an algorithm to solve it, even if the required hardware is not yet available? (3) What would be required hardware, and (4) how far is it from today's Google Sycamore processor?

Comment: The DWave folks made some progress (cf. [arXiv:1711.04083](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.04083)). We're far away from the hardware implementation stage though.